# Convergence testing involving factorial and square root

Tags: limits, convergence-divergence, factorial

> I'm trying to find the convergence of this using the ratio test:
>
> $$\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{t!}}.$$

But I'm getting no luck! Can anyone help?

(sorry I've not quite mastered MathJax notation, I'm getting there!)

Comment: I think you need to change the running index of that sum from $\;i\;$ to $\;t\;$ , don't you?

Answer (score 3):

Observe:

$$\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\dfrac{\frac{1}{\sqrt{(t+1)!}}}{\frac{1}{\sqrt{t!}}}=\sqrt{\frac{t!}{(t+1)!}}.$$

Now apply ratio test (couple steps in between are left to you).

Comment: Thank you! I did this, and got r = 1 which means the test was inconclusive, although the textbook says the limit is zero and therefore converges. Am I right in thinking that the next steps are:

sqrt(1/t+1) = sqrt(1+1/t)
And as t-> infinity, r tends to 1 which means the test is inconclusive.

Answer (score 0):

$$\sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{1}{\sqrt t!}$$

Ratio Test

$$\lim_{x \to \infty} |\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}| = L$$

$$|\frac{1}{\sqrt {(t+1)!}} \cdot \frac{\sqrt t!}{1}| = \frac{\sqrt{t!}}{\sqrt{(t+1)!}}$$

From Wolfram, 
$$\lim_{t \to \infty} \frac{\sqrt{t!}}{\sqrt{(t+1)!}}= 0$$

Since $L= 0 <1$, $$\sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{1}{\sqrt t!}$$ converges absolutely $\implies$ it converges in the usual sense.

**Edit**
From Don Antonio's comment:

$$\lim_{t \to \infty} \frac{\sqrt{t!}}{\sqrt{(t+1)!}}= \lim_{x\to \infty} \sqrt{\frac{t!}{(t+1)!}}$$

$$\frac{t!}{(t+1)!} = \frac{t \cdot t-1 \cdot t-2 \cdots 2 \cdot 1}{t+1 \cdot t \cdot t-1\cdot t-2 \cdots 2 \cdot 1} = \frac{1}{t+1}$$

$$\lim_{x \to \infty} \sqrt{\frac{1}{t+1}} = \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{t+1}} = \frac{1}{\infty} = 0$$

Comment: thanks for answering Zhoe, I've had a look at Wolfram, but it doesn't say how they got 0, unfortunately I got 1 so I'm at a loss right now!

Comment: I've been thinking of how to calculate it, but I havent gotten very far either. The only thing I can think of to justify it, is like how $\frac{1}{t}$ would be $\frac{1}{\infty}$ which $\to 0$ since it is "1/very large" and clearly getting closer to $0$, the same principle would apply since you'd have ${\frac{\sqrt{\infty}}{\sqrt{\infty +1}}}$ which is "large/very large" (where the denominator is larger) so it would $\to 0$ as well. But that hardly is solid.

Comment: Yep, same here! I'm tempted to settle with that but I know I've got to use some of these tests to prove it

Comment: If you rely too much on WA you might get unpleasantly surprised one day...: $$\frac{\sqrt{t!}}{\sqrt{(t+1)!}}=\sqrt\frac{t!}{(t+1)!}=\sqrt{\frac1{t+1}}= \frac1{\sqrt{t+1}}\xrightarrow[t\to\infty]{}0$$